# RODBC sqlFetch function crash

Tags: r

I'am trying to use package `RODBC`to access a mdb-file.
The mdb-file is created with ESRI GIS.
I want to change some entries in the attribute table.
If i try

```
sqlQuery(channnel = rddall, "SELECT* FROM abt_F;") 
sqlFetch(channel=rddall,"txt_L ")
```

R crashes.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVRye.png)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-12    brew_1.0-6      Hmisc_3.15-0    ggplot2_1.0.0   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.37-7
[7] lattice_0.20-29 rgdal_1.1-8     sp_1.2-2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] acepack_1.3-3.3     cluster_1.15.3      colorspace_1.2-5    digest_0.6.8        foreign_0.8-61     
 [6] gtable_0.1.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26 MASS_7.3-35         munsell_0.4.2       nnet_7.3-8         
[11] plyr_1.8.3          proto_0.3-10        RColorBrewer_1.1-2  Rcpp_0.11.5         reshape2_1.4.1     
[16] rpart_4.1-10        scales_0.2.4        stringr_0.6.2       tcltk_3.1.2         tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely too late, but I just came across this question after encountering a similar problem. R was crashing for me when I tried to `sqlFetch` a table directly from my ArcGIS-created .mdb, and when I tried to fetch the table via a different non-GIS .mdb (I added the table to that database as an External Linked table, from the GIS .mdb). I finally got R to load the table correctly when I created a query in my non-GIS .mdb that basically replicated the initial table (although I dropped some of the unneeded columns in that query). Now, I just left the query as-is in my non-GIS .mdb, and `sqlFetch` the query, and it's working fine. Not really an R solution, but a potential workaround that may work for some folks.